# NSData to NSString losing data

Tags: nsstring, ascii, nsdata, nsstringencoding

I'm attempting to convert a binary file into text, the problem is that a large portion of the file was not encoded in ascii and ends up being special characters.  I'm using

```objc
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but am only getting a few characters back in a 20000 byte data block.  What I would like to be able to see is all of the text (even if most is nonsense), which is what I get when I open the file using a binary editor.

[image]

Comment: Pass the correct encoding?  This sounds like an XY Problem.  What are you trying to do with the string exactly?

Comment: There isn't really a 'correct encoding' for the entire file.  Portions of the file [are readable with UTF8 or Ascii](http://i.imgur.com/OveTMs3.png) in a binary editor, but when I do a UTF8 or ascii encoding using the NSString methods I get very little or no data.  I'd like to be able to view all of the characters to do some regex and pull out the pieces that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a binary file. To read it, you find the documentation for the file format, then you parse it. Trying to throw it all into an NSString* seems absolutely pointless.

Comment: There are applications in reverse engineering, which is why hex viewers exist.  Is there no way to view the contents of the file, [like this binary editor showing the file in UTF8 encoding?](http://i.imgur.com/OveTMs3.png)

Comment: Of course. You'd use an encoding where every 8 bit character is valid. NSASCIIStringEncoding is no such encoding. UTF-8 is no such encoding. MacRoman or Windows1252 will do fine.

Comment: Yep, using an arbitrary 8-bit encoding would do it.  The other option is to loop through character-by-character, translating using a table you define.  Fairly easy to do -- the hard part is defining the table.  (Offhand, Windows1252 appears to match what's being displayed in the image above.)